# Cut square diagonally with inside content with CSS

Tags: website-design, css

I am trying to do some thing like this in CSS...

[image]

I have tried using the `border-bottom` and `border-top` but when I add text inside, something like "1 new" or something else it doesn't fit in that triangle area. I know this is because we set a `border`.

Any idea how I can do it?

Comment: Could you post a bigger image, it is very little.
Also please post an image of what you are trying, so that we can see what is wrong. THX

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You'll need to separate the content and triangle to different elements.

I would have a main container to define the box everything is going to sit in, use a pseudo-element to create the triangle, then have another element to position the content on top.

So the markup would look like this:

```
<p class="box">
  <span class="content">1 NEW</span>
</p>
```

And the CSS like this:

```
.box {
  /* we need this to position the pseudo-element */
  position: relative;

  /* set a fixed size */
  width: 6em; height: 6em;

  /* this is just to style the content */
  padding: 6px;
  color: white;
  text-align: right;
  }

.box:before {
  /* we need this to create the pseudo-element */
  content: "";
  display: block;

  /* position the triangle in the top right corner */
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 0;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;

  /* create the triangle */
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
  border: 3em solid transparent;
  border-top-color: green;
  border-right-color: green;
  }

.content {
  /* position the content above the triangle */
  position: relative;
  z-index: 1;
  }
```

[image]

You can see a working example here: https://jsfiddle.net/u79dazht/1/

#### Some resources that may help:

- https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Pseudo-elements
- https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/css-triangle/